# How to update/render a list of checkboxes with changing list in Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngfor

I want to display multiple checkboxes using ngFor, as I get the information if the checkbox is checked from the backend.
I saw an unexpected behavior and I am not sure how to solve this problem.

The problem is:
When I select a checkbox and the backend data (the observable) changes, the manually set checkbox moves.

Here is a short demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nzhkwd?file=src%2Fmain.ts
In the demo, I simulate a transfer of new array values from the backend (toggling the first value in the array (ON/OFF)). The displayed checkboxes are shown and work as expected.
But when selecting another checkbox, this selected checkbox "moves".

I tried:

- ngIf to be sure the array is available
- added ngAfterViewInit to trigger the detectChanges
- I changed the ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush
- I inspect in browser the behavior: the id of the changed element would be rendered later...

Do you guys have any idea how I can prevent this behavior?

Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm confused...

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect thing for `ngModel` and two-way-binding. First I create a object. This gives secure that the array can be sort correctly from the backend. Then bind it to the checkboxes.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-brrgdn?file=src%2Fmain.ts) is a Stackblitz

**Working code for your Stackblitz `main.ts`**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngFor="let box of checkboxes$ | async">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="box.check"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      {{box.name}}
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  toggle = 0;
  checkboxCheckedStates = [
    [{name: 'ON', check: true}, {name: 'OFF', check: false}, {name: 'OFF', check: false}],
    [{name: 'OFF', check: false}, {name: 'OFF', check: false}, {name: 'OFF', check: false}],
  ];
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<{name: string, check: boolean}[]>([]);
  checkboxes$: Observable<{name: string, check: boolean}[]> = this.subject.asObservable();
  //   <input type="checkbox" [checked]="box==='ON'"> dd
  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
     this.toggle = (this.toggle + 1) % 2;
     this.subject.next(this.checkboxCheckedStates[this.toggle]);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Comment: If you're **not** inside a formGroup it's **not** necesary [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: Hey Flo, thanks for your answer. I tested it in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-brrgdn?file=src%2Fmain.ts
In my case, if I select another checkbox, it will be toggled too, after each change from the "backend".

Comment: Added stackblitz zu answer. And here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-brrgdn?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if you understand me correct. Now, the checkbox is not moving to other checkboxes, now it toggles all checkboxes (not the wished behavior) :-(

Comment: You think to complex.... Tell me: What is the expected if new data arrived from backend "while" you working on the available data? Normaly you get data one time, then send it back and the backend handles conficts (e.g. other user edit, too). But your frontend should not refresh data automatically which the user should edit.

Comment: Ok, you're right, in your described case, it's working. Our problem is, that the data can be changed while runtime from the user and from the backend. Not in the example: (change)="..." to transmit the new value to the backend.

Use case 1: User makes no changes in GUI (no own selection), but the backend sends a new array with a dynamic length via websocket.

Comment: Use case 2: User makes changes in GUI, then the new values will be transmitted to the backend, but the backend will send new array back via websocket (because it does not know, if another user changed the setting). But the selection should be the same.

Comment: Use case 3: User makes changes in GUI, other user makes changes to. Now, the selection in your GUI are not the same, but via the new array from the backend, your selection and the selection of another user should be visible.

The main problem is: It's required to get changing data/arrays without some sideeffects with moving checkbox selections or toggling all checkboxes.

I hope my problem is a bit clearer.

Comment: Its a bad practice to handle this like you say. Websockets are fine for chat, games - all real time communication. But form data should not be changed in "real" time if any other user change it. Think: What will happen if 100 people work on same data? chaos! Get data one time, update it, let backend handle it

Comment: I am totally with you! The thing is, we don't have a choice because I have a real-time application, but it's almost safe to say that at most three people would change the values and then probably not at the same time.